# What is the difference between Debian contrib & non-free and how do they correspond to Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: software-sources, debian

I have been trying to understand the difference between Debian's contrib and non-free sections as described in [Chapter 2 of the Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html).

Are contrib packages just wrappers around non-free softwares? Like what we have in `flashplugin-nonfree` in Ubuntu?

Secondly, does the nonfree section of Debian correspond to Ubuntu's multiverse or restricted repositories or is it the union of both?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`non-free` is for packages which are straight-up not free. The only requirement is that they are redistributable. The Debian project considers that `non-free` is not a part of Debian, and is only provided as a convenience for users.

`contrib` is for packages which are themselves free but depend on packages that are in `non-free`. It's also not considered a part of Debian.

As Debian doesn't have the `main`/`restricted` and `universe`/`multiverse` distinction (and Ubuntu doesn't have the `non-free` and `contrib` distinction), the union of `non-free` and `contrib` corresponds roughly to the union of `restricted` and `multiverse`.

Comment: Note that contrib also includes (or at least has included in the past) packages where the content of the package itself is free but non-free content is auto-downloaded by the package's maintainer scripts.

Answer (score 32):

In a nutshell, these are what Ubuntu's archive divisions mean:

1) `main`: Free software, officially supported by Canonical

2) `universe`: Free software, NOT supported by Canonical

3) `restricted`: Non-free software officially supported by Canonical (includes device drivers mainly, amongst others)

4) `multiverse`: Non-free software NOT supported by Canonical (flashplugin-nonfree comes over here)

Debian has these divisions:

1) `main`: All free software that follows the DFSG (Debian Free Software Guidelines)

2) `contrib`: Free software that follows DFSG but depends on software in `non-free`.

3) `non-free`: All kinds of non-free software that doesn't follow the DFSG.

Since Debian doesn't differentiate among packages on the basis of support (since all packages are supported by the Debian community), `contrib` and `non-free` packages correspond to `Restricted`/`Multiverse` in Ubuntu. By default, all `contrib` and `non-free` packages enter `Multiverse` when they are synced. If Canonical intends to support them, they are moved to `restricted`.

Comment: Probably the difference between contrib and non-free could have been better explained like [Iain Lane](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27513/what-is-the-difference-between-debian-contrib-non-free-and-how-it-corresponds-t/27514#27514) did

Comment: Bilal Akhtar have accuracy here in this explained answer. Is that are in: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList